# Lambda Expression Java Conversion

Tags: java, user-interface, optimization, lambda

Im quite new to the new Java features and was wondering how I could convert this bit of code into a lambda expression?

```
tc.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue());
});
```

This is what IntelliJ Idea IDE is giving me.

[image: Thsi is]

Comment: It's already a lambda, remove the `return`.

Comment: @Maroun-Maroun its a statement lambda but not a Expression Lambda

Comment: @janos the return at this place is optional. If used it must not generate any compilation errors, I'm I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your IDE means is likely:

```
(p) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue());
```

No `return` needed.